# Angular 4 smooth animation

Tags: css, angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

I'm trying to do a kind of Homepage in Angular 4 with different cards like stats, charts etc using some animations.
For the chart cards I made an icon button to toggle the div to make it bigger (fullscreen-like). The animation code currently works this way:

```
state('small', style({position: 'relative', width: '50%'})),
state('large', style({
    transform: 'translateY(-150px)',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%'
})),
transition('small => large', animate('600ms ease', keyframes([
    style({position: 'absolute', width: '100%', offset: 0}),
    style({transform: 'translateY(-150px)',  offset: 1.0}),
]))),
transition('large => small', animate('600ms ease', keyframes([
    style({transform: 'translateY(-150px)',  offset: 0}),
    style({width: '50%', right: 0, offset: 1.0}),
])))
```

This doesn't work as expected since for the first step (small => lage) the width is not animated, and for the reverse animation the translate is not either.
I would like to do something "smoother" but I've been struggling for days to make it.

Here is a [quick plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8L3wShVoUOPO9qSY06d?p=preview) I made to show you what I did and the different things I tried (commented) (first plunkr don't judge me x)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will be able to get the desired animation effects by not using keyframes and switching to using ease-in-out transitions. If you were to edit your plunkr with these changes to the states and graphAnimation trigger:

```
animations: [
        trigger('panelAnimation', [
            state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
            transition('void => *', animate('600ms ease-in', keyframes([
                style({opacity: 0, offset: 0}),
                style({opacity: 1, offset: 1.0})
            ])))
        ]),
        trigger('graphAnimation', [
            state('small', style({
              position: 'absolute', 
              right: 0, 
              width: '50%'
              transform: 'translateY(0px)'
            })),
            state('large', style({
                transform: 'translateY(-150px)',
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 0,
                width: '100%'
            })),
            transition('small => large', animate('600ms 0.2ms ease-in-out')),
            transition('large => small', animate('600ms 0.2ms ease-in-out'))


        ])
    ]
```

That should give you effect you are looking for. Alternatively you could look into using groups to allow independent animation timings.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for ! =)